# Make shorter options in WebForms dropdown

Tags: html, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I create dropDownList in WebForms and bind List of some data ('Title' and 'Id')  to it.

```
Ddltitlelist.DataSource = submissionTitleList;
Ddltitlelist.DataTextField = "Submission_Title";
Ddltitlelist.DataValueField = "Submission_Id";
Ddltitlelist.DataBind();
```

But when Title is too long it looks not nice. I try to manualy set `max-width` to the select options but this doesn't work.

So my idea is to set max-width to options and add "..." when title is too long and add title to every option (when hover on some option there will be displayed something like standart tooltip ). But first of all i need to limit width of select options.

Comment: You need a plugin (javascript) for transform dropdownlist (select) to achieve what you want. The use of css on a select element is very restrictive. I recommend Jquery. - http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-selectbox-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but one method you can do is to limit the length of the text in SQL. Something like this

```
select Submission_Id,
Left(Submission_Title, 20) as Submission_Title
from Submission
where ....
```

Another option is to adjust the length after the databind and trim it that way

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Ddltitlelist" runat="server"
    OnDataBound="Ddltitlelist_DataBound">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Ddltitlelist_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in Ddltitlelist.Items)
    {
        string text = li.Text;

        // set tooltip on drop down
        li.Attributes.Add("title", text);
        // if over 20 characters, trim to fit
        if (text.Length > 20)
        {
            // trim to 17 and add 3 periods for an ellipsis
            li.Text = text.Substring(0, 17) + "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be solution for me. Just one note : in my case `li.Attributes("title", text);` in invalid. I write `li.Attributes.Add("title", text);` instead

Comment: Ah, I'll fix that. I was just typing here without testing it, glad it worked.